# Does a simple subalgebra have to be an ideal of the larger algebra?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras

A simple Lie Algebra $A$ is defined to only contain the ideals $\{0\}$ and $\{A\}$ i.e $[A,0] \subset 0$ and $[A,A] \subset A$.

However, when this algebra $A$ is a subalgebra of a larger algebra $L$, does someone describing a subalgebra $A$ being 'simple' require that $[L,A] \subset A$ (or still only that $[A,A] \subset A$ as before)?

(In other words, does the definition of an 'ideal' change to include all elements in the largest algebra now?)

The reason I ask this question, is in the context of semi-simple Lie Algebra decomposition into a direct sum of simple subalgebras. Does this statement alone imply that the simple subalgebras are ideals of the full semi-simple Lie Algebra?

Comment: Try some simple examples (like given in the answers). This is always helpful and often gives an answer to several questions one has. Then one has a good feeling having solved these alone without the help of others (and this is the aim, isn't it?).

Comment: My main quetion is really why decomposition into specifically a *direct* sum of specifically *simple* Lie subalgebras is the only obvious decomposition of a semi-simple Lie Algebra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following facts hopefully clear the fog.

- It is possible for a simple Lie algebra $L_1$ to be a sub Lie algebra, but not an ideal, of a bigger simple Lie algebra $L_2$. For example, consider $L_1=\mathfrak{sl}_2$ as a subalgebra of $L_2=\mathfrak{sl}_3$. Obviously $L_1$ is not an ideal, and both the Lie algebras are simple. In fact, a fundamental tool when developing the structure theory of simple Lie algebras is to observe that to each root there is a corresponding copy of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$.
- However, when we talk about a direct sum of Lie algebras, $L_1\oplus L_2$, then this alone implies that $[L_1,L_2]=0$. It follows that both $L_1\oplus 0$ and $0\oplus L_2$ are automatically ideals of $L_1\oplus L_2$.
- So when we decompose a semi-simple Lie algebra into a direct sum of simple ones, those summands are automatically also ideals by the previous bullet.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is negative. Take, for instance$$\mathfrak{so}(3,\Bbb R)=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0&a&c\\-a&0&b\\-c&-b&0\end{bmatrix}\,\middle|\,a,b,c\in\Bbb R\right\},$$which is a simple Lie algebra. Then $\mathfrak{so}(3,\Bbb R)$ is a subalgebra of$$\mathfrak{sl}(3,\Bbb R)=\{M\in\mathfrak{gl}(3,\Bbb R)\mid\operatorname{tr}M=0\}.$$But, for instance, if you take$$M=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix},$$then $M\in\mathfrak{sl}(3,\Bbb R)$, but$$(\forall a,b,c\in\Bbb R):\left[\begin{bmatrix}0&a&c\\-a&0&b\\-c&-b&0\end{bmatrix},M\right]=\begin{bmatrix}c & 0 & 0 \\ b & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -a & -c\end{bmatrix},$$which only belongs to $\mathfrak{so}(3,\Bbb R)$ when $a=b=c=0$.